# How can I use looping without interfering with the rest of my code?

Tags: javascript, loops, counter

I have made my rock paper scissors game for the odin project. I know in general that my code still needs polishing, but right now a problem I have yet to solve is how to continue my game without the need to refresh.
I have tried loops, however instead of looping the entire game, it loops the logs that are returned. I can't figure out where to put my prompt for the player selection, because it interferes with the rest of the code. I have been stuck for a while on this now, can someone give me direction as to what sort of loops I should be using, and/or how I can use a player prompt so that it is part of what gets looped.

```
const options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let playerPoints = 0;
let computerPoints = 0;


// Computer Selection
function computerPlay(){
   
    const compAnswer = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    console.log(compAnswer);
    return compAnswer;
}
// One round of the game results

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
   
    let rock = options[0];
    let paper = options[1];
    let scissors = options[2];
    let youWin = "You Win! ";
    let youLose = "You Lose! ";
    let rockWin = "Rock beats scissors.";
    let scissorWin = "Scissors beats paper.";
    let paperWin = "Paper beats rock.";
    let tie = "It's a tie, no points added."
  console.log(playerSelection);
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
        console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
        return tie;
      }
    else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === scissors){
       playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
        return youWin + rockWin;
        
    }
     else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection == paper){
        computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youLose + paperWin;
        
     }
     
     else if(playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === rock){
         computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)        
        return youLose + rockWin;
     }

     else if(playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === paper){
         playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)
         return youWin + scissorWin;
     }

     else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === rock){
         playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return youWin + paperWin;
     }
     else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === scissors){
         computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return youLose + scissorWin;
     }
     else{
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return "I'm sorry please try another answer"
     }

   
};
//Game



//player's choice

const computerSelection = computerPlay();
const playerSelection = prompt("Choose your weapon");
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
```

Comment: Can you post the loop code you tried?

Comment: Have you learned *how* to use loops yet?  The code you wrote at the end `const computerSelection = ...` can go in a function (e.g. named `playGame()`) which runs that code in an infinite loop.  At the end you can prompt to play another game or not, and if no `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that I think is getting you closer to where you're trying to go:

```js
const options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let playerPoints = 0;
let computerPoints = 0;


// Computer Selection
function computerPlay(){
   
    const compAnswer = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    console.log(compAnswer);
    return compAnswer;
}
// One round of the game results

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
   
    let rock = options[0];
    let paper = options[1];
    let scissors = options[2];
    let youWin = "You Win! ";
    let youLose = "You Lose! ";
    let rockWin = "Rock beats scissors.";
    let scissorWin = "Scissors beats paper.";
    let paperWin = "Paper beats rock.";
    let tie = "It's a tie, no points added."
  console.log(playerSelection);
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
        console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
        return tie;
      }
    else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === scissors){
       playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
        return youWin + rockWin;
        
    }
     else if(playerSelection === rock && computerSelection == paper){
        computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youLose + paperWin;
        
     }
     
     else if(playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === rock){
         computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)        
        return youLose + rockWin;
     }

     else if(playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === paper){
         playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)
         return youWin + scissorWin;
     }

     else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === rock){
         playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return youWin + paperWin;
     }
     else if(playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === scissors){
         computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return youLose + scissorWin;
     }
     else{
         console.log(playerPoints,computerPoints);
         return "I'm sorry please try another answer"
     }

   
};
//Game



let continueGame = true;

//player's choice
while(continueGame) {
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    const playerSelection = prompt("Choose your weapon");
  if(playerSelection) {
    alert(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));  
  } else {
    continueGame = false;
  }
}
```

I think a lot of the trouble you were having was due to constantly having prompts displayed - all of the `console.log` methods were firing, but due to the browser dealing with the `prompt()` calls, your console log never updated to show them.

You were correct that a loop will allow you to play multiple rounds on your game - I modified your code a bit so that the last three lines sit inside a while loop, which is exited if the user presses "cancel" on the prompt that pops up.

If this doesn't fully answer your question, please expand a bit on what the desired behavior is, and I'm sure I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a function just for setting the games, compute the scores, etc. Then, you can make another function that asks if the user wants to play again (put the call to the last line of that function so it gets executed after all the things has been finished). If yes, run the function. If not, return false.
Something like this might work:

```
function game(){
// all the logic go's here
ask();
}
function ask(){
var wantToPlayAgain = window.confirm("Want to play again?");
if(wantToPlayAgain == true){
game();
}
else{
return;
}
}
```